# VASP calculation error

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, quantum-chemistry

I got the error when running Vasp Calculation: Error EDDDAV: Call to ZHEGV failed. Returncode = 11 1 1. Can any one help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a diagonalization routine error. You can try to change IALGO parameter (48 or 38).

I would recommend you also try to run your calculation on a different number of processors and/or switch LSCALAPACK to FALSE in your INCAR file.

If the error persists, you can try to switch the LPLANE flag to FALSE (if not done already).